# Is it good practise to indent inline comments?

Tags: python, comments, pep

I found myself writing some tricky algorithmic code, and I tried to comment it as well as I could since I really do not know who is going to maintain this part of the code.
Following this idea, I've wrote quite a lot of block and inline comments, also trying not to over-comment it. But still, when I go back to the code I wrote a week ago, I find it difficult to read because of the swarming presence of the comments, especially the inline ones.
I though that indenting them (to ~120char) could easy the readability, but would obviously make the line way too long according to style standards.

Here's an example of the original code:

```
fooDataTableOccurrence = nestedData.find("table=\"public\".")
if 0 > fooDataTableOccurrence:  # selects only tables without tag value "public-"
    otherDataTableOccurrence = nestedData.find("table=")
    dbNamePos = nestedData.find("dbname=") + 7   # 7 is the length of "dbname="
    if -1 < otherDataTableOccurrence:  # selects only tables with tag value "table="
        # database resource case
        resourceName = self.findDB(nestedData, dbNamePos, otherDataTableOccurrence, destinationPartitionName)
        if resourceName:  #if the resource is in a wrong path
            if resourceName in ["foo", "bar", "thing", "stuff"]:
                return True, False, False  # respectively isProjectAlreadyExported, isThereUnexpectedData and wrongPathResources
            wrongPathResources.append("Database table: " + resourceName)
```

And here's how indenting inline comments would look like:

```
fooDataTableOccurrence = nestedData.find("table=\"public\".")
if 0 > seacomDataTableOccurrence:                                                                       # selects only tables without tag value "public-"
    otherDataTableOccurrence = nestedData.find("table=")
    dbNamePos = nestedData.find("dbname=") + 7                                                          # 7 is the length of "dbname="
    if -1 < otherDataTableOccurrence:                                                                   #selects only tables with tag value "table=" 
        # database resource case
        resourceName = self.findDB(nestedData, dbNamePos, otherDataTableOccurrence, destinationPartitionName)
        if resourceName:                                                                                # if the resource is in a wrong path
            if resourceName in ["foo", "bar", "thing", "stuff"]:
                return True, False, False                                                               # respectively isProjectAlreadyExported, isThereUnexpectedData and wrongPathResources
            wrongPathResources.append("Database table: " + resourceName)
```

The code is in Python (my company legacy code is not drastically following the PEP8 standard so we had to stick with that), but **my point is not about the cleanness of the code itself, but on the comments**. I am looking for a trade-off between readability and easy understanding of the code, and sometimes I find difficult achieving both at the same time
**Which of the examples is better? If none, what would be?**

Comment: Adding comment on top of the code with a space increases it's readability.. So, you can go with that.

Comment: I agree what @prisoner_of_azkaban said, If your write your function name meaningfully it should be fine.

Comment: According to pep-8 standards, in-line comments are relatively distracting. I would rather go with comments on top of code.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is an XY_Problem?
Could the comments be eliminated altogether?

Here is a (quick & dirty) attempt at refactoring the code posted:

```
dataTableOccurrence_has_tag_public = nestedData.find("table=\"public\".") > 0

if dataTableOccurrence_has_tag_public:
    datataTableOccurrence_has_tag_table = nestedData.find("table=") > 0

    prefix = "dbname="
    dbNamePos = nestedData.find(prefix) + len(prefix)

    if datataTableOccurrence_has_tag_table:
        # database resource case
        resourceName = self.findDB(nestedData, 
                                   dbNamePos, 
                                   otherDataTableOccurrence, 
                                   destinationPartitionName)

        resource_name_in_wrong_path = len(resourceName) > 0

        if resourceNameInWrongPath:

            if resourceName in ["foo", "bar", "thing", "stuff"]:
                project_already_exported = True
                unexpected_data = False
                return project_already_exported, 
                       unexpected_data, 
                       resource_name_in_wrong_path

            wrongPathResources.append("Database table: " + resourceName)
```

Further work could involve extracting functions out of the block of code.